# Hubble's Law for non-fundamental observers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

**FRLW Universe:**

$a(t$)  :  Scale factor

$H(t)=d(a(t))/a(t)$  :  Hubble Factor

$x(t)$   : Distance between the two observers

Two non-fundamental observers have a relative peculiar velocity of $v_p = d(x)/dt$, the proper distance between them is given by $r(t)=a(t)x(t)$.

Derive an expression similar to Hubble's Law.

Comment: Done! anything else?

Comment: Could you write it here, I can only get: v(t)=H*r(t)+vp*(da/dt).

Comment: But I think it should be : v(t)=Hr(t)+vp

Comment: You may want to lead with that next time, you'll definitely get an answer if you show exactly where your problem is. Expression with 'show', 'derive', 'prove', 'do', $\cdots$ are frowned upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\frac{{\rm d}#1}{{\rm d}t}}$
$$
\dd{{\bf r}} = \dd{(a{\bf x})} = \dd{a}{\bf x} + a\dd{{\bf x}} = \frac{1}{a}\dd{a}(a{\bf x}) + a\dd{{\bf x}} = H{\bf r} + a{\bf v}_p
$$